# How to use lxml in Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, lxml

In my project I need to parse an XML document using `lxml.etree`. I'm novice in Python, so I can't understand, how to find all categories with some tag. Let's describe it more accurately.

I have an XML like:

```
<cinema>
  <name>BestCinema</name>
  <films>
    <categories>
      <category>Action</category>
      <category>Thriller</category>
      <category>Soap opera</category>
    </categories>
  </films>
</cinema>
```

Now I need to get the list of all categories. In this case it will be:

```
      <category>Action</category>
      <category>Thriller</category>
      <category>Soap opera</category>
```

I need to use:

```
tree = etree.parse(file)
```

Thank you, any help is welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it should be as simple as:

```
from lxml import etree
el = etree.parse('input.xml')
categories = el.xpath("//category")
print(categories)
...
```

Everything else you should find in the [tutorial](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html).